# How do you express intention (for + gerund English structure) in Chinese?

Tags: translation, verbs

As [I've said before](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1495/15412) I'm completely illiterate in Chinese but I'm struggling to do some vital translations for my job. I am trying to make the following noun phrase in chinese:

> a proposal for creating a website

I know a little about [Chinese articles](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14709/indefinite-article-vs-numeral-use-of-%E4%B8%80-y%C4%AB). So those `as` before `proposal` and `website` are not necessary.
also from [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/) we'll have:

- proposal == 建議
- for == 為了
- create == 創造
- website == 網站

But how should I express intention in Chinese grammatically?
Are there any structure equivalent to `preposition+gerund English structure` in Chinese?
Or should I use the noun form of the verb (`Creation == 創造`)?
The translation suggested by [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/translate/) is as follows:

> a proposal for creating a website == 用於創建網站的建議
>   Is it exactly true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no indication of you actually studying Chinese, I could just give you the answer by providing the correct Chinese phrase .

However, other users who are actually studying Chinese can benefit from a more detailed answer.  I would make here.

In English, the grammar structure of "a proposal for creating a website" is:
"A" (classifier) + " proposal" (noun) + "for creating a website" (adjective phrase)

A word for word translation in Chinese would be 「一個建議，有關創立一個網站的」

The problem is, the  (classifier)+ (noun)+( adjective phrase) structure  is rarely used in Chinese grammar;

We use (classifier) + (adjective phrase) +(noun) structure in Chinese instead. So the sentence should be 「一個(有關創立一個網站的)建議」

- 「的」 in 「有關創立一個網站的」is needed to indicate「有關創立一個網站」 is a adjective phrase, (the same rule apply to adjective clause, relative phrase and relative clause)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

http://ce.linedict.com/dict.html#/cnen/example?query=proposal

The first example seems quite close to what you need.

1. 他提了个建议。

Tā tíle gè jiànyì.

He put forward a proposal.

Just squeeze web page in there:

他提出了一个网页的建议。